# Getting data from Firebase using orderByChild query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a String stationName and I want to fetch distance from FireBase according to the stationName I provided.
Here is my Firebase Database:

[image: Firebase node structure]

I am using orderByChild query to filter result and I need fetch only the distance value. Here is my code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stations").orderByChild("Name").limitToFirst(1).equalTo(sourceName);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String distance;
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            distance = dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue(String.class);
            tt.setText(distance); //to check if it is working or not
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I need to know what is wrong with code. It's not returning any value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're reading from `dataSnapshot` in your loop, but should read from `snapshot`. So `snapshot.child("Distance").getValue(String.class)`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, I got the logic.

Comment: I changed getValue("String.class") to getValue().getString() and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            distance = dataSnapshot.child("Distance").getValue(String.class);
            tt.setText(distance); //to check if it is working or not
        }
```

With this

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            distance = snapshot.child("Distance").getValue().toString(); // you 
            //cannot pass the String.class as in the getValue() parameters becasue a long value 
            //can not be cast to class object so you need to call toString() method to convert long value 
            //into the string value.
            tt.setText(distance); //to check if it is working or not
        }
```

Hope it helps